# Counting up numbers that are not lost on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, timer, counter

I need a number that will be shown as people registered on web site. The nuber will be digits which should be counted without losing value. E.g. It should start from 1 and go on, if I refresh page, it shouldnt start again from 1. It should go on. 
Example which is similar but it is not saving:

```
    var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
    var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
    var totalSeconds = 0;
    setInterval(setTime, 1000);
    function setTime()
    {
        ++totalSeconds;
        secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%60);
        minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60));
    }

    function pad(val)
    {
        var valString = val + "";
        if(valString.length < 2)
        {
            return "0" + valString;
        }
        else
        {
            return valString;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

When you refresh the page all the memory that JavaScript has created is lost.

Some options could be:

**HTML5 Local Storage**: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

**Cookies**: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

a server-side **database** such as MySQL

There are also **services** that can help with this, such as: http://www.webestools.com/pages-views-counter-free-number-pages-views-statistics.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How to this using php?

Comment: You can use PHP to read and write from a MySQL database. Here's a link that provide a good start: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp